# How to perform Touch and Hold Operation with code?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

Like we have [performClick()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#performClick()) method to simulate click event for `views` like button, similarly do we have any method by which we can simulate Touch and Hold operation with java code.

I wrote code which simulate touch event but it don't have ability to perform hold operation with touch.

Here is my code:

```
private void onMyTouchDownEvent() {
        pause.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(0,0,MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 100,100,0.5f,5,0,1,1,0,0));
    }

    private void onMyTouchUpEvent() {
        pause.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(0,0,MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 100,100,0.5f,5,0,1,1,0,0));
    }


    pause.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   storiesProgressView.pause();
                                                    return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:     storiesProgressView.resume();
                                                    return true;
                }
 
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Here is Java code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import ateam.com.stories.API.CheckNetwork;
import ateam.com.stories.API.StoriesProgressView;
import ateam.com.stories.ApacheFileUtils.FilenameUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements StoriesProgressView.StoriesListener,View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private StoriesProgressView storiesProgressView;

    private String[] resources = {  "http://www.selfilife.com/temp/sample1.png",
                                    "http://www.selfilife.com/temp/sample2.png",
                                    "https://images2.alphacoders.com/548/548276.jpg",
                                    "http://www.selfilife.com/temp/sample4.png",
                                    "http://www.selfilife.com/temp/sample5.png",
                                    "http://www.selfilife.com/temp/sample6.png"
                                 };

    private ImageView       image;
    private int counter     = 0;
    //private int tcounter    = 0;
    private boolean isTouched;

    private View    reverse,skip,pause;
    ProgressBar     pb;
    Long newduration = 5000L;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        image               = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        storiesProgressView = (StoriesProgressView) findViewById(R.id.stories);
        pb                  = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);

        reverse             = findViewById(R.id.reverse);
        skip                = findViewById(R.id.skip);
        pause               = findViewById(R.id.pause);

        reverse.setOnClickListener(this);
        skip.setOnClickListener(this);

        storiesProgressView.setStoriesCount(resources.length);  // <- set stories
        storiesProgressView.setStoryDuration(newduration);      // <- set a story duration
        storiesProgressView.setStoriesListener(this);           // <- set listener
        storiesProgressView.startStories();                     // <- start progress

        //tcounter = counter;
        //Log.d(TAG,"resources[counter] = "+resources[counter]);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resources[counter]);
        if(FilenameUtils.getExtension(resources[counter]).toString().toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase("png") || FilenameUtils.getExtension(resources[counter]).toString().toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase("jpg"))    {
            //Log.d(TAG,"image is there");
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            loadImageFromPicasso(resources[counter]);
        }   else    {
            //Log.d(TAG,"video is there");
            image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        pause.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                storiesProgressView.pause();
                return true;
            }
        });

        pause.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    storiesProgressView.pause();
                    //Log.d(TAG,"touch down");
                }
                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                    storiesProgressView.resume();
                    //Log.d(TAG,"touch up");
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext() {

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resources[++counter%resources.length]);
        //Log.d(TAG,"onNext = "+resources[counter]);
        Log.d(TAG,"counter = "+counter);

        //tcounter = counter;
        if(FilenameUtils.getExtension(resources[counter]).toString().toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase("png")  || FilenameUtils.getExtension(resources[counter]).toString().toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase("jpg") )    {
            //Log.d(TAG,"(onNext) image is there");
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            loadImageFromPicasso(resources[counter]);
        }   else    {
            //Log.d(TAG,"(onNext) video is there");
            image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrev() {
        if (counter - 1 < 0) return;

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resources[--counter%resources.length]);
        Log.d(TAG,"onPrev = "+resources[counter]);

        //tcounter = counter;
        if(FilenameUtils.getExtension(resources[counter]).toString().toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase("png")  || FilenameUtils.getExtension(resources[counter]).toString().toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase("jpg"))    {
            Log.d(TAG,"(onPrev) image is there");
            image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            //image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadImageFromPicasso(resources[counter]);
        }   else    {
            Log.d(TAG,"(onPrev) video is there");
            image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        if (counter == resources.length - 1) {
            //image.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(resources[0]));
            //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resources[0]);
            //image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            Log.d(TAG,"onComplete = "+resources[counter]);
            finish();
            //storiesProgressView.startStories();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // Very important !
        storiesProgressView.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.reverse:  storiesProgressView.reverse();
                                break;
            case R.id.skip:     storiesProgressView.skip();
                                break;
            default:break;
        }
    }

    private void loadImageFromPicasso(String url) {

        Log.d(TAG,"picasso loading url = "+url);

        if (CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(this))
        {
            //yes, internet is available
            //onMyTouchDownEvent();
            //pause.performLongClick();
            //storiesProgressView.pause();
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.get().load(url).placeholder(R.color.gray).into(image, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Log.d(TAG,"picasso success");
                    storiesProgressView.setStoryDuration(newduration);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"picasso success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //onMyTouchUpEvent();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Log.d(TAG,"picasso error");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"picasso error , counter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //onMyTouchDownEvent();
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"no internet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            image.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gray);
            image.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning);
            //Picasso.get().load(url).placeholder(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning).into(image);
            //storiesProgressView.destroy();
            //onMyTouchDownEvent();
            //storiesProgressView.pause();
        }
    }

    private void onMyTouchDownEvent() {
        isTouched = true;
        pause.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(0,0,MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 100,100,0.5f,5,0,1,1,0,0));
    }

    private void onMyTouchUpEvent() {
        isTouched = false;
        pause.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(0,0,MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 100,100,0.5f,5,0,1,1,0,0));
    }

}
```

How I can achieve hold with touch operation?

Answer (score 0):

I know how you can Perform this one, Once I have Performed this kind of thing. what you have to do is,

```
            btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // perform you task for button or view is hold 
                    Log.i("TAG", "ACTION_DOWN");
                }

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                    // perform you task for button or view is released after hold 
                    Log.i("TAG", "ACTION_UP---ACTION_CANCEL");
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: it not work with code , but work only when i touch device screen and one more thing you should put && condition between `ACTION_UP` with `ACTION_CANCEL`.

Comment: can you plz explain your requirements. exactly what do you want to perform ? also upload your detailed code

Comment: I'm developing story like module [like whatsapp and insta]. i follow [this](https://github.com/shts/StoriesProgressView) project to implement such feature. i am displaying image from network using picasso. but this library have static time to display particular image even if it not loaded into imageview it will skip that image and switch to new one. and what i want is the till moment image not loaded into imageview, it should not switch to new image. when image successfully loaded into imageview from network then it should switch to new image. like our social app display stories to us.

Comment: this answer is correct just return true at the end.